# Unable to generate logs after running rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

After running the rails s i cannot see logs on the terminal the code is working properly without any issue. The logs are getting generated logs/development.log file  As there are no logs i am unable to use debugger

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.3 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[95163] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[95163] * Version 4.1.1 (ruby 2.4.6-p354), codename: Fourth and One
[95163] * Min threads: 2, max threads: 2
[95163] * Environment: development
[95163] * Process workers: 2
[95163] * Phased restart available
[95163] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[95163] Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

config/dvelopment.log file

```
Rails.application.configure do
 
 
  config.active_storage.service = :local


  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
          
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.assets.quiet = true

  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: Rails.application.secrets[:mailer_options][:host],
    port: Rails.application.secrets[:mailer_options][:port],
  }

  # ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)

  config.lograge.enabled = true
  config.log_level = :debug
  config.lograge.formatter = Lograge::Formatters::Logstash.new

  config.lograge.custom_options = lambda do |event|
    {
      :time => Time.now.in_time_zone(Time.zone),
      :params => event.payload[:params].reject { |k| %w(controller action).include? k },
      :subdomain => event.payload[:subdomain],
      :remote_ip => event.payload[:remote_ip],
      :user_agent => event.payload[:user_agent],
      :uuid => event.payload[:uuid],
      :current_user => (event.payload[:current_user])? event.payload[:current_user][:id] : nil,
      :current_appuser => (event.payload[:current_appuser])? event.payload[:current_appuser][:id] : nil
    }
  end
  config.lograge.ignore_actions = ['PublicPagesController#status_check']

  config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 7, 204857600)

     require "awesome_print"
end
```

Comment: What does your logger configuration in `config/environments/development.rb` look like? Do I understand you correctly that you want to log to STDOUT instead of logging into a log file?

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: What do you mean "the logs are getting generated", which implies the log is working, and "unable to generate logs" which implies the opposite?

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by "As there are no logs i am unable to use debugger" - how logging to stdout and debugging are connected?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov what i want to say is after running rails s we can see the log on terminal like what are the query being , file, api;s getting hit all those stuf does not appear on my terminal which makes debugging harder

Comment: @tadman i have removed the image thanks for improving me what i mean by logs are getting generated is that i can see the logs in logs/development.log file but i want then to appear on my terminal also

Comment: @spickermann i have added config/environments/development.rb file i want to see logs on terminal also

Comment: Your configuration clearly shows that you use lograge instead of logging to stdout (what is the commented line was responsible for). Either disable lograge in favor of stdout or simply call `tail -f <path to your log file>` in a separate console session and it will show you live logs almost like the default config does...

Answer (score 1):

When you want to log to `STDOUT` in `development` environment instead of into a log file, then change this line in your `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.logger = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 7, 204857600)
```

to

```
config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Run Puma on single mode and it would bring the logs back.

You must set `workers 0` at Puma config file or remove the line.

It seens yours is setted up with `workers 2`